# jQuery checked rows, create array of checked rows 1st column and post with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, http-post, row

I am using this jscript at the moment to delete rows from an html table, however I need it also to send a POST to sql-delete.php in order to remove it from the SQL server as well.

```
$(".deletebutton").on('click', function() {
var checked = jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').map(function () {
return this.value;
}).get();
jQuery('input:checkbox:checked').parents("tr").remove();
});
```

I don't think it will be that difficult, I just need to put the first column which is a name into an array perhaps? Then send the array to sql-delete.php and break it down from there.

If I need to clarify anything just let me know.

Answer (score -1):

You can add an additional field to your object to flag it to be deleted the next time it hits the server, rather than issuing an extra request. Obviously this requires support server side (if you're using Rails, it's a feature of the framework)

Comment: Not sure that's something I can do. I am using mysql is there a way to do that?

Comment: Do you mean that you call MySql directly from your HTML page?

Comment: No, it will be sending whichever rows are checked to a delete-sql.php file with ajax. I understand that part I just am not clear on how to capture the values from the table to send. If that makes sense?

Comment: What is exactly stored in the `checked` array? (That is: what did you use for the `value` in your HTML?)